# Guidelines for casting delete-votes on questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

After 10,000 reputation, you get the ability to cast delete votes on already closed questions, but I couldn't find any guidelines on what kinds of questions should be deleted.

So are there any such guidelines?

Comment: On the central Meta.SE site: [When should I vote to delete?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58842)

Comment: Also see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/

Answer (score 23):

In general, these are the guidelines I follow when deciding if a closed post should be deleted:

**Is it obvious spam or trolling?** Make sure you flag those, but you could vote to delete if you want.

**Is it completely off topic ("Why can't I login to Facebook?", "What's the best ear medicine for hamsters?")?** Feel free to vote to delete those. There's no hope of recovering them.

**If it is a bad question, but about programming in some way, has the asker had sufficient time to edit the question into shape since it was put on hold?** If not, I would give them the time to take a shot at editing this. The [Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion) will eventually take care of questions that don't get repaired, anyway, so you don't need to worry that much about them. If the question has been closed for several days, has no redeeming value, and the Roomba hasn't taken care of it, I don't have a problem with casting a delete vote on that.

**Does it have a good answer?** If so, I only delete those in the most extreme circumstances. I also tend to decline many flags by people who want to delete their own downvoted questions that have good answers. I don't like removing useful information, even if it was given in response to a bad question. That's my personal preference, but others will disagree.

There are always exceptional circumstances, such as plagiarized questions used to farm reputation, softball questions that were only asked so that someone's sock puppet or coworker could answer with a wrong answer, etc., but the above guidelines cover how I approach delete votes for questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow really needs a site for overflow. I see this is on its way to deletion: [Python debugging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips). I understand its not a good fit for Stack Overflow and it should be closed. But the impending delete is going to cause it to go away forever. Its a shame that questions like these are terminated with the same prejudice as bad questions, rather than preserved somewhere.

Comment: @jww In theory, there's a lock for questions like these but in practice it's not used as much.

Comment: @jww - You're right, that question deserved a historical lock to prevent deletion, so I added one.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** delete a post that:

1. Is providing some non-minuscule amount of value in its current state, usually through a decent enough answer that is likely to help other users.
2. Has some reasonable chance of being improved into an appropriate question.

Else, delete it.

Comment: This is the one that prompted me to ask - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800219/qt-versus-wpf-net. It is asking which library is "better". Should it be deleted?

Comment: @sashoalm I'm not an expert in the subject matter and thus couldn't say how much of the content there is valuable, but it certainly looks like it has a very low signal/noise ratio, in addition to likely being rather dated at this point.  I don't know enough about the topic to vote myself, but I could see it going either way.

Comment: @sashoalm I did voted to delete this one. It's a collection of nonconstructive and tldr; rants or opinions. Usually the decision whether to use C++ or C# (.NET) is being made first, which usually determines the choice of the GUI framework, making this discussion useless.

Answer (score 1):

There are here: [Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be
>   removed at the discretion of the community and moderators. Over time,
>   closed questions that are not useful as signpoints to other questions
>   may also be removed, as well as questions which have no significant
>   activity over a very long period after being asked