# Accepted answer in meta appears to differ from judgement of moderator

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Some time ago now, I flagged this question, as off topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833047/java-script-how-to-calculate-difference-between-all-elements-of-the-array

on the basis that the help page says

> Some questions are still off-topic: [...]
>   Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far..."

... and this question did not (or any of the other required stuff).

I added a note saying that I thought that this one particularly needed deletion, because it was one of those ones where someone answers it even though it's off topic, and gets accepted, reinforcing that this is OK with both the asker and answerer.

I thought that this was the right and accepted thing, based on this accepted and upvoted meta answer, which I referred to in the flag:

[People who answer questions that are CLEARLY off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260083/people-who-answer-questions-that-are-clearly-off-topic/260084#260084)

... which says

> the one somewhat (but not hugely) effective tool that we have to deal with this problem, is 
>   actually deleting these types of questions (they of course need to be closed first). If answers 
>   know that questions like these will consistently be deleted, they'll learn to not waste their time"

What I've come here to ask about is that the moderator who reviewed my flag declined it, and said

> I really don't think penalising people who give good answers is going to solve any problems with the site.

In other words, this moderator is telling me that answering off-topic questions is perfectly fine, and might even be a reason *not* to delete the question

I honestly don't mind the declined flag, since my declined rate doesn't seem too bad, but I'd like some feedback on whether this appraisal is perhaps at odds with the "standard ruling" (IE in general flagging and deletion of this sort of thing is the standard procedure, even though in this case we go with the moderator's call) or whether I have taken the meta answer referred to above in the wrong way, and actually it is not normal to delete off topic question with accepted answers...

Comment: [If I was a homework cheater,](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6534/31260) I would _love_ moderators declining flags like that

Comment: Just because a post on Meta is marked as accepted does not *necessarily* make it community consensus; it is after all just the one meta question asker that gets to mark it as such. Deleting helpful content is still not a good idea, and thus not as cut and dry as you think the issue is.

Comment: I don't think declining the flag is the right thing to do, after all it was cast in good faith and provided supporting evidence. Perhaps the correct thing to do would be to mark the flag as helpful but do nothing or ...

Comment: Did you flag the question or the answer?

Comment: *Poof* -- the question is now gone.

Comment: I flagged the question.  Possibly I should have just flagged it as "off topic", which would have been accepted as "helpful" and nothing else would have happened.  Instead I flagged it as "needs moderator attention" (deletion), and explained why I thought it did.  I'm OK that the moderator thought differently.  This question is to check whether the apparent substantial consensus at the meta question I referred to before raising this flag was in fact a good guiding principle.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I agree with the moderator who declined that flag. In general, we do not unilaterally delete questions in response to flags if the questions have good answers to them. We'll make exceptions in certain cases, but we're not going to go around deleting every downvoted and closed question with a good answer.

In general, [I do not believe that the presence of good answers to bad questions encourages more bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255861/19679). I tend to feel that deleting good answers to closed questions deprives future visitors of useful information. That is my personal opinion, which is not necessarily shared by other moderators or members of the community, but it's caused me to have a high threshold for [when I delete questions with good answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272767/19679).

As an aside, I should point out that almost all deletion requests on homework questions with good answers come from the askers themselves, concentrated around the end of university semesters. The excuses are amusing, but we all know they're trying to cover their tracks once they realize their instructors can use Google.

Finally, you really don't need a moderator to step in here. The question wasn't even closed at the time the flag was processed, despite being around for weeks, which says something about how pressing it was as a question to be dealt with. Now that people have voted to close it, the community can vote to delete this question if they want, so we're not required here.

Comment: The answer isn't exactly stellar, though - just some code (not a large amount, I admit) with no explanation. I don't see any reason to keep the question around.

Comment: I agree. It's just a code answer of a specific homework beg type question, one that will help no one in the future. No need to keep this question around.

Comment: It's amusing to know that the askers try to get their homework dumps deleted :D

Comment: +1 : " *I tend to feel that deleting good answers to closed questions deprives future visitors of useful information.* "

Comment: I've marked this answer as accepted because I found the answer that it points to a very useful counterpoint to the answer that I used to base my flag on.   That answer highlights that the issue has two strong sides to it, hard to choose between.  In the future I will just flag off topic questions as off topic, downvote, and let the machinery that's in place do the rest.

Answer (score 16):

The real issue here is that it's not the job of the diamonds to close or delete garden-variety crap. That's the job of users with close and delete privileges derived from their reputation. I appreciate that everyone wants to be able to *do something* when they see trash. Honestly, the best something you can do is push the down arrow until you have enough rep to push bigger, redder, buttons. Downvoting clears things from the front page and makes them more susceptible to eventual cleanup.

Comment: it would help if cleanup was not so _eventual_ ([What should the system be deleting automatically that it already isn't?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262077/839601)). Invoking meta effect on every homework dump won't scale. Nor using mod powers to delete garbage

Comment: +1 for "*the best something you can do is push the down arrow until you have enough rep to push bigger, redder, buttons*" ... exactly the advice I think those of us who are kind of like tweens (we've been around just long enough to make us slightly dangerous) are looking for when we want to make things better!

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the real issue is that accepting an answer is the purview of the person who originally asked the question, and this decision has no official standing.

Don't mistake popular vote and/or one person accepting a particular opinion, for official sanction.

Unfortunately.

Comment: Yes - I appreciate that, and in fact that's why I asked this question: to get for me (and provide for others?) calibration of the earlier question and its answer and how I should approach this issue when I see it next.

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Yep, a good reason to ask.